# .NET Core Azure function -> error: could not load file or assembly System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependencies, azure-functions, nuget

I have project running on .NET Core 3.1. I've created an Azure Function that references a 3rd party library (a SyncFusion library, if it makes any difference). When I try to use a specific function from that library I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: One of the linked question shows how to get the dll to Azure. But then the function fails with a System.BadImageFormatException...